# What’s that U shaped metal thing needed for tuning called?

Tags: terminology, tuning

There is this metal thing shaped as a 'U'; you hit it against something and put it against your ear to hear this sound. I'm not sure what it's called but I need it to tune the A string on my violin.

Answer (score 25):

It's a [tuning fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuning_fork):

[image]

<sub>(image taken from the [Thomann website](https://www.thomann.de/nl/km_168_stimmgabel.htm?sid=75ab08f1afedb11a1ab76a671f4bff0a))</sub>

Comment: also a "camertone"?

Comment: @enkryptor, looks like _camertone_ looks like an English-ized spelling of a foreign word for tuning fork.  There is _камертон_ in Russian and maybe _Kammerton_ in German.  I'd never heard the word, so thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 17):

If it's U shaped it won't work. It needs to be Y shaped, so the handle can be held without damping the tines. Hold the handle onto something like the violin body, and the sound will be amplified. It's usually called a tuning fork, although a couple of my students call it a pitchfork, which, actually, it could be...

Comment: The point is that the vibration travels into your skull and hit your ear drums. You bite using your front teeth right in front of the ball. The major advantage is I can flick it with a finger and immediately tune using a bow on a violin. It's actually much more useful than it sounds.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is also called a [diapason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diapason).

Comment: Albeit the word exists in English, does it really mean tuning fork in English? Or is this just the case in Romance languages like French, Spanish and Italian?